# can't send php form data info to other page

Tags: php, mysql

i have some php source it can send form data info to other page under mysql 4.x version.

but after upgraded to mysql 5.x version, this php source can't send form data info to other page.

i was searched many info, but don't have idea what's wrong with my php source.

i just can guess this is related with mysql upgrade and i have to edit my php source,

but lack of knowledge it very tough for me.

if anyone help me or give some hint it really appreciate!

sender page name is 'index.php' and i was uploaded to pastebin site

http://pastebin.com/3Sg7SyWV

and form data receiver page is 'check_form.php' and i was uploaded to pastebin site also.

http://pastebin.com/WEx5tEn2

for several day i was search and search but lack of my knowledge about php and mysql

it very hard to resolve.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand what you want to do? Do you want to submit the contents of "morningform" (from your example) to check_form.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will probably solve your question:

In `check_form.php` change:

```
$order_p1;
$order_p1_ea;
etc.
```

To:

```
$_POST['order_p1'];
$_POST['order_p1_ea'];
etc.
```

Along with upgrading MySQL on your server, most likely [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) was also turned off.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="morningform" action="./form_order/s_order_check.php" onSubmit="return orderCheck(this);">
```

Well, according to this line of code taken from the index.php, your receiver page isn't 'check_form.php'. Was it a typo on your question and is this the intended behaviour (and the 2nd pastebinned page is actually the s_order_check.php) or did you forget to change the action part of the form?